# Excel VBA - Use value in cell as address to target another cell

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first post!

I have N11 which displays a cell location that I want to place string variable x in, so when N11 reads G2, I need to enter x into G2.

I have been unsuccessful so far with:

```
   y = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, "N").Value
Range(y) = x
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305508/how-to-code-excel-vba-equivalent-of-indirect-function

Comment: Just to clarify: N11 contains a cell address that you want to programmatically update with the value of (an elsewhere defined) variable "x"?

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald N11 contains the address to which I want variable x entered. So When N11 shows $G$2 vairable x should be entered in G2.
EDIT: so N11's code is: =CELL("address",INDEX(G:G,MATCH(Sheet1!C8,A:A)))

Comment: Editing your question down to the minimum required to convey what you are looking for, what you have (i.e. minimal but complete code) and where you are stuck will get much more attention and possible answers.  Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald I have cut down my question to hopefully clear things up, thanks for your input!

Comment: You have been successful with... great then, is there still a question?

Comment: Good result!  Welcome to SO.  Good luck with your journey and learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following sub.

```
Sub PutValue()
Dim x As Date
x = #3/10/2017#

    Range(Range("N11").Value).Value = x

End Sub
```

--------------------------- Edit ----------------------

```
Sub PutValue()

    Range(Sheet2.Range("N11").Value).Value = "x"

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use any data type for `x` rather than `date` type. Test and provide feedback.

Comment: Hi, I tried the sub without success, I realised my question had gotten a bit confusing so I have rewritten is to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @HarryM So, you have 'G2` in cell `N11` and you want to put `x` in `G2` by pragmatically, right?

Comment: Now all you need to do is accept the answer by clicking the tick and give him an up-vote for his work.

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald I found that my code was working fine but as it originated from sheet 2 of my workbook and N11 simply gives "$A$1", the data was output to that location in sheet 1 which is covered by an image. Thank you both for your help!